# associated data is not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

There are a simple model Customer which has a relation with Order as 1:n.

```
class Customer 
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  has_many :orders

end
```

This piece of code,

```
customer = Customer.new name: "John"
customer.orders.build item: "ipad"  #=> doesn't work in the method create
customer.save                       #=> true
```

works on a rails4 console but doesn't work in the method create, where only the customer name is saved, but the order isn't and as if the build method is not there. As a result, the item "ipad" is not saved and no any orders happens.

I'm using rails(4.0.2) + mongoid(4.0.0.alpha1).

Any idea what's root cause?

Answer (score 1):

via http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :albums, autosave: true
end

band = Band.first
band.albums.build(name: "101")
band.save #=> Will save the album as well.
```

Cheers!

Comment: This helps a lot, but why it works on a console without the autosave option?